# Intervention Image - Could not open input file: composer.phar

Tags: laravel, intervention

When I install the `php composer.phar require intervention/image` this,

I got the one error:

> Could not open input file: composer.phar

I follow this step but I can't find the solution to my error: [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Comment: Did you install composer? https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the most recent version, run the following command

```
composer require intervention/image
```

OR

Add to `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    },
```

After, Run this command in the command prompt: `composer update`

More info: [intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image)

Comment: hi bro, i dont know how to tell the thanks, im very happy and thanks a lot 10000000000000000000000000, it's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

use just

`composer require intervention/image`

instead of

`php composer.phar require intervention/image`

Answer (score 0):

If you added composer to your system environment variables. you can call composer globally like this:
`composer require intervention/image`

### How to add composer to system environment variables

- Search "Edit the system environment variables" in start menu.
- Click on "Environment variables"
- Find "PATH" variable and edit it.
- Add your composer installation folder path. `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`

### Find your composer installation folder

You can find where composer is installed by this command:
`which composer`